# Silenced sniper rifle

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I have a tranquilzer round sniper rifle but it is not silenced thus once I fire it, whoever I hit goes to sleep (ZZZ) but the rest of troops go into alert mode.

Where/how can I find a suppressor for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few steps involved to get a suppressor for the non-lethal sniper rifle.

First, you need to develop a sniper rifle with a suppressor. It does not matter which one, as long as it has a suppressor.

The next step is to unlock the legendary gunsmith. To do that, you need to finish 3 side-ops: 107, 108 and 109. This allows you to customize weapons in your ACC.

With a developed sniper suppressor and the legendary gunsmith, you can then customize your sniper rifle and attach the suppressor.

It is worth noting that only one side op appear per region of the map.  So, you might be able to do 107 but 108 will not appear till you have completed the other side op(s) in the appropriate regions.

Comment: I highly recommend the semi-automatic AM MRS-71 tranquilliser rifle, over the bolt action RENOV-ICKX.

Comment: I did not even realize there was a semi-auto tranq rifle, but if you are going to use a bolt-action one you should use the M2000-D-NL. I compared it to the Renov tranq rifle and it's just objectively better in every way (someone correct me if I am wrong, but the game certainly seemed to indicate that from the stats). Yes, I compared it to the Renov of equivalent tier/grade and not the earliest one.

Comment: Putting this in another comment because it's important enough: You can also research assault rifles and use assault rifle suppressors on your sniper rifles. Suppressors are the same across (most) sniper rifles, assault rifles and machineguns.

Comment: I am somewhat disappointed that you cannot get a [Mosin Nagant](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Mosin-Nagant) in TPP.

Comment: @Sardathrion Uhh, that's what the Renov is. None of the guns in game are completely reflective of real guns; for some reason, Konami decided to skimp out on the licensing to use existing guns in the game this time. So the studio made fake guns that are obviously inspired by real guns, like the James Bond/007 franchise of games does. The Renov is a Mosin Nagant and I believe the M2000-D is a [Remington 700 or M24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M24_Sniper_Weapon_System). You can definitely tell because Renov's description says it was "used since WWII."

Answer (score 1):

Once you rescue the legendaty gunsmith (Side Op 109), you will unlock the ability to customise weapons from the ACC menu. Suppressors can then be attached to guns from there.